# c++ file stream behaving strangely

Tags: c++, file, stream

This is the code:

```
fstream ioF; int i = 0; string line;
ioF.open("test.txt");
while(getline(ioF, line)) cout << ++i << ": " << line << endl;
cout << i << endl;
ioF.close();

ioF.open("test.txt");
i = 0;
while(getline(ioF, line))
    if(++i == 3){
        ioF << "*";
    }
ioF.close();

ioF.open("test.txt");
i = 0;
while(getline(ioF, line)) cout << ++i << ": " << line << endl;
cout << i << endl;
ioF.close();
```

My files contains this in the beginning:

> line one
>   line two
>   line three
>   line four
>   line five
>   line six

These are the outputs after deleting line 4 to 6 one at a time starting with the second execution (each block is an execution):

> 1: line one
>   2: line two
>   3: line three
>   4: line four
>   5: line five
>   6: line six
>   6
>   1: line one
>   2: line two
>   3: line three
>   4: li*e four
>   5: line five
>   6: line six
>   6

---

> 1: line one
>   2: line two
>   3: line three
>   4: line five
>   5: line six
>   5
>   1: line one
>   2: line two
>   3: line three
>   4: l*ne five
>   5: line six
>   5

---

> 1: line one
>   2: line two
>   3: line three
>   4: line six
>   4
>   1: line one
>   2: line two
>   3: line three
>   4: *ine six
>   4

---

> 1: line one
>   2: line two
>   3: line three
>   3
>   1: line one
>   2: line two
>   3: line three
>   3

I don't understand why the cursor behaves like that, and why in the last execution the file stream doesn't print `*` to the file. Can someone please explain?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please post input and output as text, not images.  Not everyone can see images.

Comment: alright, will do

Comment: Also, that star ends up in strange places, in the middle of the word. My guess is that the fstream has some optimizations that reads ahead (and buffers) more data than the line you requested, so the "cursor" could be pretty much anywhere.

Comment: You are reading from a file, then writing to the same file.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I was trying to delete something then noticed that the cursor was strange so i made this test program

Comment: I might just be tired, but `ioF << "*";` doesn't seem right. It's a *in* stream, so you shouldn't be able to write *out* to it. Rereading again made me realize that that might be your question.